# JQuery/JS -- delete newline after a span in <pre>/<code>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the js fiddle demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/mstksg/u42bT/

I want to remove the classses "hello" and "hello2"...and remove the newlines after them, so that the blanks where they used to be "collapse".

For example, if I have

```
<pre>
<code><span>welcome
traveler</span>
<span class="hello">hello</span>
and
<span class="hello2">hello</span>
<span>world</span></code>
</pre>
```

And I run

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('.hello').hide();
    $('.hello2').remove();
});
```

(I can do either hide or remove...just trying either)

Then I see

```
welcome
traveler

and

world
```

however...I'd like to see

```
welcome
traveler
and
world
```

Is there any way to make this happen?  The key is that I can only identify what i want to "hide"/"remove" by the classes of the spans...and there might be more than one span in the code block, and at unknowable places.

**NOTE**: I am unable to change the HTML that is placed inside the code blocks; it comes to me as it is and I have no power to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this.

### HTML

```
<!-- Your code -->
<pre id="before">
<code><span>welcome
traveler</span>
<span class="hello">hello</span>
<span>and</span>
<span class="hello2">hello</span>
<span>world</span></code>
</pre>

<!-- New code -->
<pre id="after">
</pre>
```

### jQuery

```
var spans = $('#before span:not([class])');
$('#before').remove();
$('#after').append(spans);
$("#after span").after("<br />");
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FLWH/).

Comment: the `and` doesn't come wrapped in a `span`.  I can do the rest dynamically with js, but is there a way i can wrap that `and` in a `span` using js/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a css class to the element that uses the display: none attribute like this, but does not work for pre tag.

```
//css class
.hidden { display: none}

//and call it like this with js
$('.elem').addClass('hidden');
```

But you can use a regex to remove the whitespaces in the html after calling .hide() or .remove() like this:

```
$('.hello').hide();
$('.hello2').remove();  
var x = $('pre').html().replace(/[\n](<span>)/g, '<span>');
$('pre').html(x);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fpX5Z/

Comment: Sorry, htis doesn't seem to work :(  could you post a fiddle?

Comment: I didn´t know about the pre/code tags, and learned now to not post untested code! Sorry!

Comment: as this did not let me go: different approach added

Comment: doesn't work if "and" isn't in a `span` :/  it's okay though, I think I figured it out, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `<br>` inside the spans.

```
<pre>
<code><span>welcome
traveler</span><span class="hello"><br>hello</span>
and<span class="hello2"><br>hello</span>
<span>world</span></code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to change the HTML that gets put inside the spans, it comes to me as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to ->

```
<pre>
<code><span>welcome
traveler</span><span class="hello">
hello</span>
<span>and</span><span class="hello2">
hello</span>
<span>world</span></code>
</pre>
```

then your Jquery will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/u42bT/3/

If you can not change HTML, then change CSS.

[CSS Change jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u42bT/4/)

```
pre, code {
    white-space: normal;
}
code span:first-child {
    white-space: pre;
}
code span:nth-child(n+2):before {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't change the HTML that comes in the blocks :/